# How to use if statements with pandas/ csv files

Tags: python, csv, data-analysis

i want to check if the string data in a series is equal to a given string.
but this returns:
    The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

i know that to use and/or i use & / | but i don't understand how to do this with an if statement

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    if (data.Sex == 'female'):
        if data.Survived == 1:
```

*EDIT*

so what i want to do is check if the Sex column is set female for each row in the data set. what is the best way of doing this.
here is an example of what the data looks like:

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs
```

i might be doing this all wrong. please tell me if i am.

Comment: how can an entire series be equal to a single string? you mean if it exists in it?

Comment: provide an example

Comment: @sam46 i edited, hopefully this gives you a better idea

Comment: If you were to just select with your conditions: `df[(df.Sex == 'female') & (df.Survived == 1)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"sex": ['female', 'male', 'male' , 'female', 'female'],
                   "Survived": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]})
df["Survived"] = np.where(df["sex"] == 'female', 1, 0 )
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   Survived     sex
0         1  female
1         0    male
2         0    male
3         1  female
4         1  female
```